# Power Bi report builder cascading parameters from different data sources

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am new to powerbi world.. I need your help to set up cascading parameters from different data sources.

Example:

I have two data sources:
Data source1 = Contact
Data source2 = DataFact

I created two datasets from the data sources.
DatasetContact from Contact Data source,
DatasetFact from DataFact Data source

Contact has data fields:

- Email Address, Name, Fax, Address

DataFact has data fields:

- Name, Date,  Sell, Measure

Now, what I want is, i have two parameters: Name (from Datafact) and Email Address (from Contact). When i select a name from Name parameter, Email Address parameter shows only email address associated with Name (from Datafact).

Comment: Ok, did you read the docs [Add cascading parameters to a paginated report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-cascading-parameters-to-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft this docs is for SSRS. is it same for PowerBi paginated report?

Comment: Yes.  SSRS Reports and PowerBI Paginated Reports are basically the same thing.  There are some minor differences, like Power BI Paginated Reports doesn't support shared Connections.  But most SSRS knoledge is directly applicable to Power BI Paginated Reports.